# Camunda Spring Transaction Integration not working

Tags: java, spring, transactions, camunda

I'm using Camunda 7.3, Spring 4.2.4 and Hibernate 4.3.8 and I'm trying to use them with the same transaction as explained in [Camunda Documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/user-guide/spring-framework-integration/transactions/). The transaction works ok with Hibernate operations but not with Camunda operations, if a transaction rollback occurs just the hibernate operations are reverted.

```
@Configuration
public class CamundaConfiguration {

    // Variables with connection Data

    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("PostgreSQL");
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", NamingStrategyLowerCase.class.getCanonicalName());
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 0);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", true);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode", SharedCacheMode.ALL);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy", "read-write");
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.class.getCanonicalName());
        bean.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        bean.setPackagesToScan("br.com.model");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager bean = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
        bean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("org.hibernate.flushMode", FlushMode.AUTO);
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("PostgreSQL");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
        config.setConnectionTestQuery("select 1");

        HikariDataSource bean = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(bean);
    }

    @Bean
    public ManagedProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngine() {
        ManagedProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean = new ManagedProcessEngineFactoryBean();
        processEngineFactoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration());
        return processEngineFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration() {
        SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
        processEngineConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSource());
        processEngineConfiguration.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
        processEngineConfiguration.setJobExecutorActivate(true);
        processEngineConfiguration.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE);
        return processEngineConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskService taskService() throws Exception {
        return processEngine().getObject().getTaskService();
    }
}
```

The dataSource and transactionManager is the same used by Spring and Hibernate.

```
@Service
public class TaskManager {
    @Inject
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Transactional
    public void completeTask(String taskId, final Map<String, Object> variables) {

        org.camunda.bpm.engine.task.Task camundaTask = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskId(taskId).singleResult();
        taskService.complete(camundaTask.getId(), variables);

        // Hibernate Operations

        throw new RuntimeException("Exception test");
    }
}
```

When executed the code above a rollback will occur and the 'Hibernate Operations' are rollbacked but the operations executed in taskService.complete are not.

I already debugged the Camunda code and everything seems ok, I found a SpringTransactionInterceptor and the commands are executed inside a `TransactionTemplate.execute()` and at this point the transaction is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying about transactions, Jpa and Spring, I found out the problem was jpaDialect is not configured, it's responsible to synchronize JDBC and JTA transactions.

> The dialect object can be used to retrieve the underlying JDBC
>   connection and thus allows for exposing JPA transactions as JDBC
>   transactions.

I included the following code into configuration and now it's working:

```
@Configuration
public class CamundaConfiguration {
    ....

    @Bean
    public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
        return new org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect();
    }

    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        ...
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager bean = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
        bean.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        ...
        return bean;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The @Bean annotations are required in shared engines?

Comment: Same issue, but your fix doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you include more information about your configuration?